# Are there disjoint open sets separating closed sets satisfying $d(A, B) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f(x) = 1/x$. I was wondering if it was possible to find two disjoint open sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contain $A = \{(x, f(x))~|~x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $B = \{(x, 0)~|~x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ respectively. Intuitively I would have said it wasn't true because
$$d(A, B) = \inf\{d(x, y)~|~x \in A \land y \in B\} = 0$$
and since $A,B$ are closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it should not be possible to find disjoint open sets that contain $A$ and $B$ respectively (in my intuition). However, for each point of $A$ and $B$, one can find open balls of radii small enough to be disjoint. By taking $U$ and $V$ the unions of such balls, did we not explicitly construct the desired open sets? This is breaking my mind, does someone have an explication? Thank you very much!

Comment: Take tubular neighborhoods that get smaller as you approach infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $A = \{(x, 1/x) : x \neq 0\}$, then we can separate $A$ and $B$ by open sets
\begin{align*}
U &= \{(x, y) : xy < 1/2\} \\
V &= \{(x, y) : xy > 1/2\}.
\end{align*}
Note that $(x, y) \mapsto xy$ is continuous, hence $U$ and $V$ are open. Trivially, they are also disjoint. Further,
$$(x, y) \in A \implies xy = 1 > 1/2 \implies (x, y) \in V,$$
and
$$(x, y) \in B \implies y = 0 \implies xy = 0 < 1/2 \implies (x, y) \in U.$$